# Calculating centroid for complex geometric shape -- decomposing the shape

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, geometry

Question:

A rack is made from roll-formed sheet steel and has
the cross section shown. Determine the location $(x, y)$ of the
centroid of the cross section. The dimensions are indicated
at the center thickness of each segment.

[image]

The answer given by my textbook is $x = 24.4$ mm, $y = 40.6$ mm. I don't understand how they "dissect" this cross section? I calculated the centroid to be $x = 25.31$mm and $y = 40$mm which is quite similar

I separated the area into $3$ areas, like this:

[image]

How do you dissect this area?

Answer (score 2):

For this type of problem, represent each segment as a point. These points are to be located at the center of mass of their respective segments.

You can compute the individual centroid for each segment by calculating its geometric center (in the case of a uniformly dense material).

Then, apply the following equation for the center of mass $\bf \vec R$,

$${\bf \vec R} = \dfrac{\displaystyle \sum_i m_i {\bf \vec r}_i}{\displaystyle\sum_i m_i}.$$

It should look something like this:

[image]

Each pink ball represents a point mass, $m_i$.

Note that the mass itself does not matter, but the proportions do. Easiest way is to define the linear density as $\mu \equiv \dfrac{1 \rm \ mass \ unit}{1 \rm \ mm}$ such that a length of 1 mm corresponds to a mass of 1 unit.

Comment: This is really awesome! thanks. -Sarah